How to Calculate the Scale of a TikZ Map and Create Commands for Plotting Points by Latitude and Longitude?
I am working with the TikZ map of India provided in the link. The map uses Cartesian coordinates to define locations of different states. I want to achieve the following:

Calculate the scale of the map:
I already know the Cartesian coordinates of several states from the
TikZ code. I also know the geographical latitude and longitude of
these states. How can I compute the scale of the map (in terms of
units per kilometer) by comparing the Cartesian distance with the
actual geographical distance and scale it to the point where it is
sort of accurate for me to plot in this above example graph

Plot the map on an A4 page:
I want to fit this TikZ map neatly on an A4 page, ensuring proper
scaling.

Create custom commands:
I want to define a new command that allows me to plot points or
annotate locations on this map by specifying their latitude and
longitude (e.g., \plotpoint{latitude}{longitude}{label}). Could
someone help me with the approach or provide examples for:



Calculating the scale from two known points (Cartesian and
geographical distances).
Dynamically transforming latitude/longitudeinto TikZ coordinates using the calculated scale.
Writing a TikZ command for plotting points using these transformed coordinates.

Any guidance or code snippets to get started would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is a (Mercator) projection of a sphereical surface onto a plane.  The grid itself is nonliear.  You would need several points to nail down the relationship to lattitude and longitude.

Welcome. // Hm, too many questions (== problems) at once, no example given. Better post one or more very focused questions. // Wrt. A4 I suggest to (A) replace the class with standalone from your link + compile, (B) \usepackage{graphicx} to include the pdf from A e.g. in class article. See e.g. here for an example how to deal with both files: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730821/245790
